# Would every prayer without pre-written words be called mental prayer?

Tags: catholicism

Some people people say that we have two kinds of prayer, i.e. vocal and mental prayer.

When I looked up the term mental prayer in Catholic dictionary I found this:
"The form of prayer in which the sentiments expressed are one's own and not those of another person and the expression of these sentiments is mainly, if not entirely, interior and not externalized."

When I looked up vocal prayer I found this: "The form of prayer that is a "conversation" with God, or the angels and saints, and is formed in words or equivalent symbols of expression. More technically, vocal prayer involves the use of some set formulas, since it is assumed that even when a person prays mentally he necessarily employs some form of at least internal speech."

It seems to me that Catholic dictionary says that mental prayer is simply prayers without pre-writtten words.
On the other hand it seems that it says that vocal prayer can refer to that things as well. It does say that vocal prayer sometimes refers to prayers with pre-written words.

It also seems to say that you can do vocal and mental prayer at the same time.

Would every prayer without pre-written words be called mental prayer?

Comment: Which Catholic dictionary?

Comment: Catholoc Dictionary. That is what it is called. Or perhaps there are more than one dictionary with that name.

Comment: According to Servant of God John A. Hardon (Modern Catholic Dictionary ): The form of prayer in which the sentiments expressed are one's own and not those of another person and the expression of these sentiments is mainly, if not entirely, interior and not externalized. Mental prayer is accomplished by internal acts of the mind and affections and is either simple meditation or contemplation. As meditation, it is a loving and discursive (reflective) consideration of religious truths or some mystery of faith.... (cont'd)

Comment: ... As contemplation, it is a loving and intuitive (immediately perceptive) consideration and admiration of the same truths or mysteries of faith.  In mental prayer the three powers of the soul are engaged: the memory, which offers the mind material for meditation or contemplation; the intellect, which ponders or directly perceives the meaning of some religious truth and its implications for practice; and the will, which freely expresses its sentiments of faith, trust, and love, and (as needed) makes good resolutions based on what the memory and intellect have made known to the will.

Answer (score 0):

The Rosary is a good example of doing mental and vocal prayer at the same time.  You say the words of the Rosary while meditating on the mysteries and at the same time the words of the Rosary.

St. Louis DeMontfort's "Secret of the Rosary" is a good reference for getting the most of the prayers contained in the Rosary.

Usually, however, prayer isn't broken down into Mental vs Vocal - but

- Vocal (meaning rote prayers, that can be prayed mentally; i.e. without speaking)
- Meditative
- Contemplative

Meditative prayer is prayer where you may read

Contemplative prayer is a deeper form where God provides the direction. Ideally, someone progresses from Vocal to Meditative to Contemplative prayer (maybe never quite reaching contemplative prayer) but never abandoning one for the other because vocal prayer, like the Rosary, Mass and Liturgy of the Hours is prayed in common by the oldest monks and the smallest children and it is still for the benefit of their souls; it also will always have a meditative element to it (note the pauses).

There may be less opportunity for contemplation while vocal prayers are happening and for that, if you want to do it in communion, Eucharist Adoration is a great option.

- https://www.usccb.org/catholic-prayers good resource on meditation  and adoration
- http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p4s1c3a1.htm#2723 Types of prayer in the Catechism